# How I can get authentication token or do loging in Elastic Search using REST API? For example from POSTMAN

Tags: rest, authentication, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying to list data from Elastic Search using the REST API on Postman.
But I get a `security_exception` error

I read the elastic documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-get-token.html
but didn't  work.

I'm using Elastic 7.2

```
Method: POST

Content-type: Application/json

URI: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/_security/oauth2/token

BODY: 

{
  "grant_type" : "password",
  "username" : "user_name",
  "password" : "correct_password"
}
```

I need this service to return the authentication token. But this is the response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "security_exception",
                "reason": "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_security/oauth2/token]",
                "header": {
                    "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_security/oauth2/token]",
        "header": {
            "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
        }
    },
    "status": 401
}
```

Comment: can you explain step by step what u are doing? is `_securty` is your index?

Comment: I need list data from any index example: 
"GET http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/name_index/name_type/_search"

using postmant or any external client.

But my elastic use authentication by "user/password"


How I can list my index data using that REST SERVICE?

I think need get the authentication token before then put the token 
into the rest request.

This is the documentation of use the SECURITY API
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-get-token.html

Can you help me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try to do a basic authentication instead. And pass in the body just the grant_type.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can create a new user using the following command: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/users-command.html

For instance, you can create a new user with the "superuser" role like this:

/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-users useradd DESIRED_USERNAME -r superuser

You'll be prompted to enter a password.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows OS:

Open command prompt as admin

run command `cd 'elasticsearch-bin-folderpath-on-local-system'`

```
bin>elasticsearch-users useradd username -p password -r superuser

bin>elasticsearch
```

when prompted for username and password give the username and password set after the useradd command